# В чем принцип записи catch(Exception $e) в php?

Tags: php, try-catch

Наприммер:

```
 class AClass
{
  /*
  *@param BClass $obj
  */
  public function someFunction(BClass $obj)
  {

  }
}
```

Здесь мне все понятно в свойство someFunction класса AClass может попасть только экземпляр класса BClass или вот пример

```
function(BInterface $obj){}//аналогично, только унаследованный от интерфейса
```

И прошу заметить мы туда подставляем значения только когда вызываем функцию или делаем экземпляр класса а вот что эта за форма записи - я не понимаю - расшифруйте пожалуйста - я же нигде не указывал $e и вообще могу вместо $e написать любую переменную

```
catch(Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: Это type hinting, обозначения типа, который должен прийти в функцию/catch-блок. В первом случае несоответствие вызовет ошибку, во втором - игнорирование catch-блока.

Comment: исходя из этого допустимо писать $my_param= new  MyClass();  echo  myFunction(MyClass $my_param); и это не будет ошибкой?

Comment: будет, такая запись допустима в объявлении функции, но не в вызове

Comment: catch(Exception $e) {} а мы здесь обьявляем функцию или вызываем - у меня именно здесь непонимание

Comment: это не функция вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы правы, вместо $e вы можете написать любую переменную. Но вся суть в том, что catch - это не функция, а перехватчик исключений. Этот механизм работает в всязке с try.

```
try {

... code
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  код исключения
}
```

\Exception - это базовый класс для всех исключений от которого вы можете наследовать свои исключения. Exception e- говорит о том, что вы хотите перехватывать все исключения.

если вы наследуете свой тип исключения
например:

```
try {

... code
}
catch (CustomException $e) {
  код исключения
}
```

то перехватываться будут только ваши исключения из CustomException.

Наследование исключений выглядит так [Наследование исключений](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.extending.php)

```
class SomeException extends Exception
{
         public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
    parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
}

public function __toString() {
    return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
}

public function customFunction() {
    echo "Мы можем определять новые методы в наследуемом классе\n";
}
}
```

а перехват пользовательского исключения

```
try {

... code
  if(УСЛОВИЕ) {
       throw new MyException('1 - неправильный параметр', 5);
   }
}
catch (CustomException $e) {
  echo "Поймано собственное переопределенное исключение\n", $e;
}
```

Comment: перехватчик исключений - это означает что для него свой собственный синтаксис, разработанный программистами php и нет необходимости задумываться в строке catch (CustomException $e) потому что такая форма записи присуща только для него ? если так то это будет полезно знать.

Comment: это общий синтаксис как и java С++ итд. Это механизм. Синтаксис 
for(i=0; i < 100; i++) {
   
} 
у вас же не вызывает вопросов?

Comment: Это  операторы. которые действуют в связке

Comment: for($i=0;$i < 100; $i++) { } - вот как раз раньше вызывал, когда читал статью о производительности, оказалось что можно записывать и так for(;;){} - прокатит и так for($i=0,$size=sizeof($b);$i<$size;$i++){}. Спасибо большое - теперь буду воспринимать это как должное без подтекстов

Comment: ещё есть finally (условие которое будет выполнятся всегда). И перехват исключений может состоять из 3х операторов. 
try {

}
catch(Exception) {

}
finally {
  
}
тоесть 3 оператора try в котором условие, catch - оператор перехватчик и finally блок в который выполнится при любых обстоятельствах

Comment: Пожалуйста, я тоже эту тему не сразу понял :)

Comment: принцип действия я понял из статьи на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/264417/ и с этого момента началось мое развитие а вот принцип записи вы мне помогли осмыслить - благодарю

Comment: вот ещё 1 вариант использования for for(i=0; i < a.length; a[i++] = 0); :)